# Set value to customer custom address attribute in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer-address, address-attribute

I have created a multi-select attribute(attribute_code is **address_purpose**) for the customer using UpgradeData

The options are created and the values are getting stored if I edit in magento admin.

But they are not updating once updated programmatically with addressId.

I have two Options Delivery, General.

So I am updating address using below code with the addressId.

```
  $addressPurpose = array("Delivery","General");
  $shippingAddressId = 15;
  $address = $this->_addressRepository->getById($shippingAddressId);  
  $address->setCustomerId(1);
  $address->setFirstname('test');
  $address->setLastname('test');
  $address->setCountryId('GB');
  $address->setPostcode('TW9 1AF');
  $address->setCity('Test');
  //$address->setData('address_purpose',$addressPurpose);
  //$address->setAddressPurpose($addressPurpose);
  $address->setCustomAttribute('address_purpose', $addressPurpose);
  $address->setTelephone('1213323213');

 $this->_addressRepository->save($address);
```

This code is not saving value for my custom attribute(address_purpose).

What is the problem here? Please, anyone support on this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are saving `multiselect` attribute you have to store option id instead it's value

```
public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
           'option1' => [
            'label' => 'Delivery',
            'value' => 'delivery'
        ],
        'option2' => [
            'label' => 'General',
            'value' => 'general'
           ]
        ];
     }

$addressPurpose = array("option1","option2");
$address->setCustomAttribute('address_purpose', $addressPurpose);
$this->_addressRepository->save($address);
```

Comment: this will work if we have two option given, if only one option it doesn't work. example: $addressPurpose = array("option1");

Comment: it is working for me for multiselect attribute

Comment: Provide like this and try, $addressPurpose = array("option1");, will it select only one item?

Comment: Yes @jafarpinjar it's strange but try for single in your case `$address->setCustomAttribute('address_purpose', 'option1');`

Comment: if i provide option explicitly, it works, try to assign it to variable and save, does it work for you

Comment: Ofcourse it work! it's same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89126/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-ketan-borada).

Answer (score 0):

`$address = $this->_addressRepository->getById($shippingAddressId);` vs.  `$this->addressRepository->save($address);`?

Variable once with leading underscore and once without. I suppose that's only a typo in your posting. The rest of the code seems to be ok and should save the custom attribute in my opinion.

I would suggest to debug data in the save method in `AddressRepository` especially what happens with your address data before and after `$addressModel->updateData($address);`

Comment: sorry, its my mistake, but still value not getting saved..

Comment: if you call `$address->getCustomAttribute('address_purpose');` after `$address->setCustomAttribute('address_purpose', $addressPurpose);` does it return the correct value? If yes I would try to dump address data (original and changed object) to logfile in the mentioned method in my post. If not it might be a problem with your custom attribute.

Comment: Its giving me empty array..

Comment: Looks like the custom attribute has not been created correctly. Does it have the correct entity type? `entity_type_code` should be `customer_address` and `entity_type_id = 2`. Please check in `eav_attribute` table : `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'address_purpose'`

Comment: yes created correctly, if i save from admin end, its working perfectly

Comment: OK, the last idea I have is cache related, the attribute metadata is cached and it might be that this cache was not reloaded / rebuild after your attribute creation. Before setting a custom attribute Magento checks if the attribute code you try to set exists. Although I can't imagine that this could be the problem since you use the attribute in admin panel